# Replacement for istrstream(char* s, std::streamsize n) constructor?

Tags: c++, string

I have a code block that uses ***istrstream*** which is deprecated:

```
if((iss = new istrstream(inBuf, (int) msgLen)) == 0)
  {
    errId = ReadErr;
    errStr = "Failed to allocate ostrstream";
    D(cerr << "IpcSapBaseMsg: failed to allocate ostrstream\n");
}
```

I changed  ***istrstream*** with ***istringstream*** but It didn't worked.

> IpcSapBaseMsg.C:178:52: error: invalid conversion from 'msgLen_t {aka int}' to 'std::ios_base::openmode {aka std::_Ios_Openmode}' [-fpermissive]
>        if((iss = new istringstream(inBuf, (int) msgLen)) == 0)

Is there any working alternative for ***istrstream*** or any other way to solve my problem ? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  You should just be able to create a stream and add what you want to it.

Comment: `istringstream` is the replacement for `istrstream`, but its constructor takes different parameters

Comment: btw isnt your errormessage a bit confusing "failed to allocate ostrstream" when creating a istrstream failed !?!

Comment: "Deprecated" means only that it **might** be removed from the standard in the future. If you have working code, don't change it just because it uses something that's deprecated. After all, the C headers are deprecated...

Comment: Why the memory leak?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::istringstream(std::string(inBuf, msgLen));
```

should work. If `inBuf` is null-terminated, you don't need the `msgLen` parameter - you can just do

```
std::istringstream(inBuf);
```

Why `new`, though? I suggest looking into [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/basic_istringstream) before posting a question here.

Comment: Can make it appear near identical to the original code with uniform initialization , I think. `std::istringstream({inBuf, msgLen})`